# Groupby Array[Array[String]] Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, group-by

I have an Array[Array[String]] like this:

```
Array(Array("A","1","2"), 
      Array("A","3","4"), 
      Array("A","5","6"),    
      Array("B","7","8"),
      Array("B","9","10"))
```

I would like to groupby on the first element of each sub Array and get a Map like this:

```
var A:Map[String, Array[String] = Map()
A + = ('A' -> Array("1", "2"))
A + = ('A' -> Array("3", "4"))
A + = ('A' -> Array("5", "6"))
A + = ('B' -> Array("7", "8"))
A + = ('B' -> Array("9", "10"))
```

I don't know how to manipulate groupby to get this result.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Note that the `Map` you get with your second snippet will only produce `A = Map("A" -> Array("5", "6"), "B" -> Array("9", "10"))` because `Map` keys are unique identifiers. Also, `'A'` is not of type `String` but of type `Char`. Keep to the double quotes `"` for defining `String` literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
val arr = Array(Array("A","1","2"),
                Array("A","3","4"),
                Array("A","5","6"),
                Array("B","7","8"),
                Array("B","9","10"))

val result = arr.groupBy(_.head).map{case (k,v) => k -> v.flatMap(_.tail)}

result("A")  // Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
result("B")  // Array(7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Basically, after grouping you need to remove the head of each sub-array (that's the `tail` part), and you need to flatten the sub-arrays into a single array (that's the `flatMap` part).

Warning: this will throw a runtime exception if any of the sub-arrays are empty. Here's a version that will take care of that.

```
val result=arr.groupBy(_.headOption).collect{case (Some(k),v)=>k->v.flatMap(_.tail)}
```